# Hyper-threading configuration

Tags: hyperthreading

Suppose I have a machine, which has 2 x Intel Xeon x5550 quad-core processors (total 8 core). Hyper-threading is enabled.

I want to run an application on 4 cores (4 threads) with 2 physical cores and 2 threads per core (hyper-threading) instead of using the actual 4 physical cores.

Is this possible to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make sure your application has enough threads so it can utilize enough cores. After that it is the problem of the operating system to allocate cores to your application

Comment: you should have atleast 16 threads to utilize that amount of cores fully, depending on the load and type , more might be better. Assuming ofcourse that your software scales